# .htaccess RewriteRule issue, some rules not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an large `.htaccess` file with some rules. One of those rules is not working and I don't know why.

The file have I checked with: http://www.htaccesscheck.com and there are no issues.

I have 2 links in my `php`file:

```
echo '<a href="corten-stalen-borderrand-hoek-type-'.$_GET['type'].'-03'">Bestel op maat</a>
echo '<a href="corten-stalen-borderrand-hoek-getrapt-type-'.$_GET['type'].'-04'">Bestel op maat</a>
```

And in my `.htaccess` I have:

```
RewriteRule ^corten-stalen-borderrand-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-type-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ product_borderrand_hoek.php?type=$2&id=$1&image=$3
RewriteRule ^corten-stalen-borderrand-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-getrapt-type-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ product_borderrand_hoek_getrapt.php?type=$2&id=$1&image=$3
```

The second line in the `.htaccess` is not working. Any suggestions?

The page where this is about: https://torza.nl/test_environment/metaalboutique/nieuwe_versie/corten-stalen-borderranden-geheel-op-maat-gemaakt?type=1&id=2

The image below with the geen box is working OK, in the red not working ok.
Should be pointing to: https://torza.nl/test_environment/metaalboutique/nieuwe_versie/product_borderrand_hoek_getrapt.php?type=1&id=hoek&image=04
[image]

Comment: Could you please do mention which URLs you are hitting in browser and which URLs in backend you want to serve them in your question for better understanding of question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the first rule you have presented; it also matches the second URL that should be rewritten according to the second rule, if I understand this correctly.
To avoid this you have to adjust the first rule to either not include `-` int he first character group

```
RewriteRule ^corten-stalen-borderrand-([A-Za-z0-9]+)-type-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ product_borderrand_hoek.php?type=$2&id=$1&image=$3
```

or, if this is not possible, prevent that `getrapt` shows up before `type`: `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(?<!getrapt)-type`

```
^corten-stalen-borderrand-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(?<!getrapt)-type-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the issue with matching both rules. I swapped both rules in the `.htaccess` file.